# Matlab doesn't add marker line in for loop

Tags: matlab, plot

I am simply trying to plot a function. I use markers and I want markers connected with line. However, when I try to plot in a `for` loop, Matlab doesn't create lines between markers. When I put the plot command out of the `for` loop, it works.

Here is a simple example:

```
y=0:10:100;

for j=1:1:11

x(1,j)=1/(y(1,j)+1);

plot(y(1,j),x(1,j),'-s','MarkerFaceColor','g','MarkerSize',6)

hold on;

end
```

This doesn't work.

---

```
y=0:10:100;

for j=1:1:11

x(1,j)=1/(y(1,j)+1);

end

plot(y,x,'-s','MarkerFaceColor','g','MarkerSize',6)
```

This works.

---

I couldn't figure out the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `plot` behaves differently for vectors and scalars.

If you give `plot` scalars (for e.g. `plot(2,3)`), it plots the point. However, if you give it vectors (for e.g. `plot([1 2 3], [1 4 9])` then it plots the points AND draws a line between them.
To only draw the points, you can use the plot options such as `plot([1 2 3], [1 4 9],'o')`.

To draw the points and lines when the values are being generated in a loop, I'd suggest creating a temporary array to store your points in as you loop and plot them outside.